# Replacing characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a compressor based on the Huffman algorithm to compress text:

```
# compressor Huffman quijote

from collections import Counter
import math
import pickle
import re
quijote = open("quijote.txt", encoding="utf8")
num_lletres = 0
llistaQ = []
for linia in quijote:
    for lletra in linia:
        llistaQ.append(lletra)
        num_lletres = num_lletres+1
c = Counter(llistaQ)
c_ordenat = c.most_common()
c_final=c_ordenat[::-1]
for i,j in enumerate(c_final):
    c_final[i]=list(c_final[i])    


diccionari=[]
for i,j in c_final:
    diccionari.append([i,None])   


while len(c_final) > 1:
    petit1=c_final[0]
    petit2=c_final[1]
    c_final.append([petit1[0]+petit2[0],petit1[1]+petit2[1]])

    for i in petit1[0]:
        for pos,x in enumerate(diccionari):
            if x[0]==i:
                val_antic=diccionari[pos][1]
                diccionari[pos].pop(1)
                if val_antic==None:
                    diccionari[pos].insert(1,"1")
                else:    
                    diccionari[pos].insert(1,"1"+val_antic)
    for i in petit2[0]:
        for pos,x in enumerate(diccionari):
            if x[0]==i:
                val_antic=diccionari[pos][1]
                diccionari[pos].pop(1)
                if val_antic==None:
                    diccionari[pos].insert(1,"0")
                else:    
                    diccionari[pos].insert(1,"0"+val_antic)                

    del c_final[0]
    del c_final[0]
    c_final.sort(key = lambda f: f[1])


s=0
entropia=0
llarg=0
llistat=c_ordenat[::-1]
for i,j in llistat:
    freq=float(j)/float(num_lletres)
    s=freq*math.log(freq,2.0)
    entropia=entropia+s
    for pos,z in enumerate(diccionari):
        if z[0]==i:
            llarg=llarg+(len(z[1])*freq)
entropia=-(entropia)


with open("taula_Huffman.txt", "wb") as taula_final:
    pickle.dump(diccionari, taula_final)

cadena=''
with open("quijote.txt", encoding="utf8") as entrada, open('Huffman sortida', 'wb') as sortida:
    for line in entrada:
        for x, y in diccionari:
            line = line.replace(x, y)
        cadena=cadena+line
    cadena=str(1)+cadena     
    bits=re.findall('........',cadena)

    for i in bits:
        sortida.write(bytes([int(i,2)]))

    ll=len(cadena)
    sob=ll%8
    a=len(cadena)/8
    inta=(int(a))
    nc=''
    for n in range(1,sob+1):
        nc=nc+cadena[(inta*8)+n-1]
    penultim=nc+str(1)*(8-sob)
    ultim=str('{0:08b}'.format(sob))
    sortida.write(bytes([int(penultim,2)]))
    sortida.write(bytes([int(ultim,2)]))


print("entropia=",entropia)
print("expected length=",llarg)

quijote.close()
```

And the decompressor:

```
#Descompressor Huffman
import binascii
import pickle

with open("Huffman sortida", "rb") as entrada, open('quijote descomprimit.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as sortida, open("taula_Huffman.txt", "rb") as diccionari:

    byte = entrada.read()
    hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte).decode()
    binary=bin(int(hexadecimal, 16))[2:].zfill(8)
    cadena=binary[1:]
    ultim=cadena[(len(cadena)-8):(len(cadena))]
    cadena=cadena[:(len(cadena)-8)]
    penultim=cadena[(len(cadena)-8):(len(cadena))]
    cadena=cadena[:(len(cadena)-8)]
    ultim=int(ultim,2)
    afegit=penultim[:ultim]
    cadena=cadena+afegit

    dic = pickle.load(diccionari)

    dicc={}
    for i in dic:
        dicc[i[0]] = i[1]
    dicci = {v: k for k, v in dicc.items()}    


    temporal=''
    text=''
    for i in cadena:
        temporal+=i
        if temporal in dicci:
            text+=dicci[temporal]
            temporal=''
    sortida.write(text)
```

The problem is that the decompressed file is fine except for the numbers, I mean, where on the original file were letters in the final file there are the same letters, but where on the original file were numbers in the final file apears a series of *1111 Csicauicau,11dunrdunr dunrdunrdunrdunr 111 1111dunrdunr dunrdunrdunrdunr* or whatever.

So I found that the part of the compressor that failed was the replace instruction (line 74-75):

```
for line in entrada:
    for x, y in diccionari:
        line = line.replace(x, y)
    cadena=cadena+line
```

I replaced that four lines by the following:

```
for line in entrada:
    for ch in line:
        for x, y in diccionari:
            if ch==x:
                cadena=cadena+y
                break
```

The problem is that this makes the program so slow (~40 seconds to run on my PC).  The first option was about 9 seconds on my PC.

Is there a way to do this **for** inside a **for** inside a **for** faster? Or, is there a solution to my .replace(x,y) which fails with the numbers?

Comment: Have a look at [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Comment: line[line.index(x)] = y ??

Comment: it's only an alternative. try and replace it with your line.replace and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia I don't understand what do you mean... :S

Comment: look at your question. Do you see the third block of code you have. The one where you say you found the part of your code that fails. Yeah?    change the:                                                                                           
 "line = line.replace(x,y)"                                                                            
to:                                                                                     
 "line[line.index(x)]  = y"

Comment: all I'm suggesting is another way to do it that may or may not make your code faster. try it. You won't loose anything.